# "Speak a British accent" vs. "speak in a British accent"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *speak an accent* and *speak in an accent*? For example:

> You put on your resume that you can **speak a British accent**. Could you demonstrate it?

You put on your resume that you can **speak in a British accent**. Could you demonstrate it?

Comment: "You put on your resume that you can speak ***with*** a British accent. Could you demonstrate it?"

Comment: The [smart-aleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_aleck) reply to the first question is of course 'Sure. "A British accent." See?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You speak a *language*, you don't speak an ‘accent’:

*“Jorge is from Barcelona, he speaks Spanish and English. Although his English is very good, he **speaks it with** a [strong Spanish accent](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/strong-accent)”*.

From *[Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/accent)*

> ## accent
>
> ### collocations
>
> **have an accent**
>
> - *The man had a Spanish accent.*
>
> **speak with an accent**
>
> - *She spoke with an accent that I couldn’t understand.*

> **a strong/broad/thick/pronounced accent** (=very noticeable)
>
> - *She spoke with a strong Scottish accent.*
> - *a broad Australian accent*

> **an upper-class/middle-class/working-class accent**
>
> - *Sebastian spoke with an upper-class accent.*

You can also say “speak **in a(n)** adjective (language)”

From YouTube, a tutorial entitled: [How To Speak In An American Accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5T3ubSdhSM)
Funnily enough, the presenter is British and **has a** *posh* English accent.

Comment: [ONE language, THREE accents - UK vs. USA vs. AUS English!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66aG5P0kQpU)

Comment: Note that it seems [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+in+an+accent%2Cspeak+with+an+accent&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20in%20an%20accent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeak%20with%20an%20accent%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cspeak%20in%20an%20accent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeak%20with%20an%20accent%3B%2Cc0) to speak *with* an accent than to speak *in* an accent. (The use of *in* sounds odd to me, although not wrong.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I would probably say that someone "speaks **in** a funny/strange/Spanish, British, French etc. or foreign accent" rather than "speaks **with** a foreign accent"  a The word accent in the former, I feel, is often preceded by an adjective.

Answer (score 4):

The video mentioned above 'How to speak **in** an American accent' was made by a British person who is giving some tips to speak in a different accent.

This is because when you speak in an accent that isn't your usual one, then you speak *in an accent. For example, 'Can you speak in an Indian accent'?

For the above example, you can also use 'do'. For example, 'Can you do an Indian accent?'

I'm a native speaker of British English and I would say the following:

He has a Cockney accent. (no need for a preposition).
He speaks with an accent. (his accent shows he is not from here).
Julia is speaking in a silly accent. (changing her accent for a moment for fun).

Answer (score 3):

“Speak” means to say something, and you say words, not accents.

The correct way to say this is:

> speak **in** a British accent

Comment: @choster Thanks for that, I’m actually going to remove it from my answer as it’s extraneous and, as you point out, potentially hazardous!

Answer (score 1):

We say that we speak a language as in

> I speak Spanish

but we speak in an accent or with an accent

> He speaks in a Geordie accent
> She speaks in a Scouse accent

Where the first speaker comes from the north east of England and the second from Liverpool. There is not really a common British accent although people would probably understand you to mean you speak with an accent of educated people within the area immediately around London.

Comment: A language isn't the only thing you can speak, for instance: "I speak the truth"

Comment: @Chebi that is perfectly true but I was trying to suggest a usage which might have been confused with accent.